# How a great candidate looks from your perspective?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I am sending the upper question to a recruiter. I am trying to ask him what makes a great candidate.

Comment: ***What does** a great candidate **look like** from your perspective?* But this is effectively Off Topic proofreading.

Comment: "I am trying to ask him what makes a great candidate."  How about "What makes a great candidate?"  Since this is your phrase and not ours.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am anew user. What do you mean my question is off topic ?

Answer (score 0):

This is too vague.  You're asking the recruiter to be a professor.

Better, "What makes a great candidate for position XYZ?" to get his opinion.  He should be motivated to help, as he only gets paid for filling the job, and other recruiters are competing.

Also, get rid of "from your perspective."  It is stilted and phony.  You're asking him, right?  Who else's perspective?

Comment: Thanks. Are you a bit too strict with me ? I am a learner. Moreover, how do you mean by "stilted and phony" ?